# What were the effective dates of this 1968 Delaware law and this 1967 Nevada law?

Tags: law

What were the effective dates of each of these two laws? I am asking for purposes of my academic research, which relates to the history of the American family.

1. [1968 Delaware, 124th General Assembly, Chapter 296.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7VzKV1GxxEzTkk2US1EbUpEWWc/view?usp=sharing)
2. [1967 Nevada, 54th session, Chapter 278.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7VzKV1GxxEzaHpackhvMF9rNlE/view?usp=sharing)

The effective dates are not mentioned in either of the two laws. Usually the state's statute books or constitution would provide for when a law becomes effective, if it is not explicitly stated in the law itself. But for Delaware and Nevada I have not been able to find such information.

(Pending the establishment of Law.SE, I thought History.SE was the next best place to ask this. Please let me know if there is a more appropriate SE for this question.)

Comment: Probably off topic, but a quick Google search turns up [this page](http://www.statescape.com/resources/legislative/bill-effective-dates.aspx) with time frames for each state.  For NV, the relevant statute is [NRS 218D.330](https://www.leg.state.nv.us/NRS/NRS-218D.html#NRS218DSec330).  In DE, it would seem to be the court's interpretation of Article III §18 of the [DE constitution](http://www.state.de.us/facts/constit/welcome.htm), but I didn't locate a statute or relevant case law.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answers are, respectively, June 11, 1968 and July 1, 1967.

The source for my answer for Delaware is this [Supreme Court of Delaware decision](https://scholar.google.com/scholar_case?&case=1396065497948473115).

For Nevada, the present law is that the default effective date is October 1 ([NRS 218D.330.](https://www.leg.state.nv.us/NRS/NRS-218D.html#NRS218DSec330)).

However, as the legislative history of that law states, it was amended in 1925, 1989, and 2011. The [1989 amendment](https://www.leg.state.nv.us/Statutes/65th/Stats198901.html#Stats198901page2) changed the default effective date from July 1 to October 1. Thus, the default effective date of Nevada laws between 1926 and 1988 would have been July 1.

For these answers I must credit Comintern's comment for the initial clues.